# Mongoose and mapReduce - map function not called

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm attempting to use the mapReduce function of Mongodb via Mongoose, but the map function I'm passing in is never called.  Here is the data currently contained in the "Post" model collection:

```
[ { data: 'Tag test data',
name: 'Tag Test',
_id: 5130dff2560105c235000002,
__v: 0,
comments: [],
tags: [ 'tag1', 'tag2', 'tag3' ] },


 { data: 'Testing tags.  Again.',
    name: 'Another test post',
    _id: 5131213b611fe1f443000002,
    __v: 0,
    comments: [],
    tags: [ 'tags', 'test', 'again' ] } ]
```

Here is the code:

```
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var PostSchema = new Schema ({
   name : String
   , data : String
   , tags : [String]
});
mongoose.model('Post', PostSchema);


var o = {};

o.map = function() {
    if (!this.tags) {
        //console.log('No tags found for Post ' + this.name);
        return;
    }
    for (index in this.tags) {
        emit(this.tags[index], 1);
    }
}

o.reduce = function(previous, current) {
    var count = 0;
    for (index in current) {
        count += current[index];
    }
    return count;
}

o.out = { replace : 'tags'}
o.verbose = true;

var Post = mongoose.model('Post');

Post.mapReduce(o, function(error, model, stats) {
    console.log('model: ' + model);
    console.log('stats: ' + stats);
});
```

The "model" and "stats" objects are always undefined, and the log statements in the map function are never called.  If I do something like this with the Post model outside of the mapReduce function, I get the data at the top of the post as expected:

```
Post.find().exec(function(err, posts) {
    console.log(posts);
});
```

Any suggestions?  I'm sure something is just slightly off...

Comment: You can't call `console.log` from within the map and reduce functions as it's not supported by Mongo's JavaScript engine.

Comment: The output of the console.log statements is "model: undefined".  I also can't operate on the model object with normal mongo functions as it throws an undefined error.

Comment: you may be passing the wrong format to mapReduce call - you can call db.runCommand() with a single object which has to have {mapReduce:'collection', map:< >, reduce: < > , etc}.  All helpers expect (map, reduce, {other options}) - can you try that syntax?

Comment: @Geoff I assume you've registered a schema for 'Post' elsewhere in your code?  If I add that and remove the logging from map and reduce then it works.

Comment: @JohnnyHK Yes, I do define the 'Post' model earlier in my code.  I've updated the code above to reflect my recent changes, but I'm still getting the model and stats as undefined in the mapReduce function.  Perhaps I've defined the model incorrectly?  Are the log statements in the mapReduce function printing actual data for you?

Comment: @Geoff Yes, they output: `model: function model(doc, fields, skipId) {
    if (!(this instanceof model))
      return new model(doc, fields, skipId);
    Model.call(this, doc, fields, skipId);
  }
stats: [object Object]
`

Comment: @JohnnyHK Geez, the simplest thing... I thought I'd removed all the 'console.log' statements from the map and reduce functions, but I overlooked one.  It's working fine now. Thanks a ton for your help.  If you want to post your very first statement as an answer, I'd be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't call `console.log` from within the `map` and `reduce` functions as it's not supported by Mongo's JavaScript engine.

Answer (score 1):

To debug your map/reduce/finalize functions you can use the MongoDB [print](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/getting-started-with-the-mongo-shell/#print) statement. The output will be added to your Mongo log file.